# Related to death penalty

Tags: reference-request

Is there somewhere a list of all countries in the world that have death penalty and of when someone can/must be punished by death penalty?

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capital_punishment_by_country) gives a list, though not a single table (it's separated by continent). You may have to look into country-specific laws (e.g. the definition of "aggravated robbery" which triggers execution in Sierra Leone, witchcraft in Saudi Arabia, or violation of state ideology in North Korea.